# From BS formula how to show Euro-call values go up and Euro-put values go down with interest rates?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, interest-rates

The BS formula gives, as quoted from Wikepdia:

> $${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}C(S_{t},t)&=N(d_{1})S_{t}-N(d_{2})Ke^{-r(T-t)}\\d_{1}&={\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {T-t}}}}\left[\ln \left({\frac {S_{t}}{K}}\right)+\left(r+{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2}}\right)(T-t)\right]\\d_{2}&=d_{1}-\sigma {\sqrt {T-t}}\\\end{aligned}}}$$

in which all notations are standard (I don't think any notational ambiguity exists; otherwise please refer to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black.E2.80.93Scholes_formula) directly.)

I want to show that when everything else is fixed, $C$ will go up with $r$. Or alternatively, that $\partial C/\partial r\ge 0$. But it turns out the sign of the partial derivative is not that obvious.

To convince myself somehow, I drew a couple of $C$-$r$ plots on my computer using various sets of parameters and found out the curve always went upwards as expected. But I still want a rigorous proof in the mathematical sense. So am I missing something here? Is there anybody who can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a call, the rho is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial r} &= \frac{\sqrt{T-t}}{\sigma}\left(S_t\phi(d_1)
-Ke^{-r(T-t)}\phi(d_2)\right)+K\,(T-t)e^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{T-t}}{\sigma}\left(S_t\phi(d_1)
-Ke^{-r(T-t)}\phi(d_1-\sigma\sqrt{T-t})\right)+K\,(T-t)e^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{T-t}}{\sigma}\left(S_t\phi(d_1)
-Ke^{-r(T-t)}\phi(d_1)e^{d_1\sigma \sqrt{T-t}-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)}\right)+K\,(T-t)e^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)\\
&=K\,(T-t)e^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2).
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \frac{\ln \frac{S_t}{K}+\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}, \
d_2 = d_1-\sigma\sqrt{T-t}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, for a put, the  rho is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial P_t}{\partial r} =- K\,(T-t)e^{-r(T-t)}N(-d_2).
\end{align*}
It is now obvious that the call is an increasing function of the interest rate, while the put is a decreasing function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model for a reference.

Comment: How do you obtain such simple expressions... I did the calculation twice and each time it gave me a horrible mess.

Comment: See the reference I provided above. For a specific derivation, you may need some careful algebraic manipulations

Comment: At time $t$, $S_t$ is a known quantity, we do not treat it as a function of $t$. At time $0$, $S_t$ depends on $r$, but is also a random number.

Comment: Here's what I got: $$\rho=T(\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{T}}S_0\phi(d_1)+Ke^{-rT}(N(d_2)-\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{T}}\phi(d_2))).$$ For simplicity I let $t=0$, and Iet $\phi$ denote standard normal PDF. I don't see how this could simplify to the result in the reference. Could you help me identify some possible bugs? For example, I don't see how the $S_0$ term can be cancelled out.

Comment: I added some details for how to convert $\phi(d_2)$ to $\phi(d_1)$.

Comment: @Gordon: I think the sign for the call is wrong..?